# GetCurrentDirectory C# error

Tags: c#, directory

I have written a C# program that copys itself and moves in a precise source directory. It is working fine the first time it moves, but the second time the value of the current directory is wrong. To determine the file path I use :

```
string current = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

The second time the program wants to move, I call `GetCurrentDirectory` again but the value of "current" is still the old path and it gives me `FileNotFound` Error.

What can I do to make `GetCurrentDirectory()` read the new path ?

Comment: Scary question, thank heavens for UAC.  ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory property.  And Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location so you don't care.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute your application in a new process. You are likely using the original process and its current directory won't change to wherever you copied your application to.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve with your application, but definitely execute each copy as a new process and allow the current process to terminate itself.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of where you moved it.

GetCurrentDirectory() is the working directory the program is executed from.  That wont change when you simply move the executable ( it would change if you executed it again from the new location). So either create a new process and exec the exe in its new location, or just keep track location you moved it to. The later is far easier.

As a note, copying  the exe file doesn't have any effect on the running instance of the program, since it's still running from the "old" location ( likely its actually loaded in memory at this point). To the running program, the exe file copy is just a file. Why are you doing this ?

If you want to execute the new exe and exit the old one then use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) api and call

```
Process.start("new/path/to/exe");
Environment.exit(0);
```

If you are just in main, you could simply return instead of calling exit.
This should work, it might cause both programs to exit ( if this kills child processes) but I don't think it does.

Comment: It is a personal project I'm trying to achieve. I wanted to create a self-replicating program for the challenge. How can I create a new process then ?

Comment: Process.start("path\to\someexe")